# Converting MTS to MP4 using FFmpeg results in no/missing audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a few videos coming from a Sony Nex-5N. Basically they are "compiled" in an AVCHD. The format that is inside is MTS. I'm able to convert the videos losslessly but the resulting MP4 has no audio.

```
ffmpeg -i 20201205150626.MTS -c:v copy -c:a copy -an -f mp4 20201205150626.MP4
```

The result is no audio. Then I tried to select explicitly the audio track using `-map 0:a:1` but it says that it does not matches no streams. Please have a look at the following extract :

```
> ffmpeg -i 20201205150626.MTS -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:a:1 -an -f mp4 20201205150626.MP4 
ffmpeg version 4.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '20201205150626.MTS':
  Duration: 00:00:09.60, start: 1.020000, bitrate: 26296 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDPR / 0x52504448), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 100 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
Stream map '0:a:1' matches no streams.
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.
```

I can see an audio stream, and its index is 1. I have no clue what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `-an` switch in your command line. This **removes audio** from output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was there at the start, I was having issue with the metadata trying different args to fix it, forgot to remove it! Thanks again

Comment: ffmpeg is a nigthmare, a million of switches in command line makes us confused :-)

Comment: I meant it was NOT there at the start :-D but yeah, so many switches and the docs are confusing. (Still the tool is very useful and powerful and all my respect thanks to the builders :-) )